# Movement on the map

Tags: android, maps, android-mapview

How do you direct an arrow (marker) to the movement of the user?

On the emulator I move in the direction of a red arrow ([skrinshot](http://s017.radikal.ru/i438/1201/f0/57a3e04e0e32.jpg)), and the marker goes sideways.

My code,which adds arrow on map:

```
LinearLayout vGoing = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.mylocationidentificationgoing, null);
mapView.addView(vGoing, new MapView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,point,MapView.LayoutParams.BOTTOM_CENTER));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use GPS to track delta changes in Lat Long and use that to show direction of the arrow.